# How to use HTML tags in a material apex card?

Tags: html, oracle-apex-5.1

I have this problem where I need to use HTML code in my material apex card code, but I can't find a way to use HTML to have a better structure of the text showed.

Currently I have a region of type classic report, witch contains this SQL code:

```
select '#APP_IMAGES#counter.png' img_src
,'Counter' title
, 'This element is conformated by 3 sections: <ul><li>Prueba</li></ul> ' content
,' ' btn_label_1
,' ' btn_label_2
from dual
```

As you can see my content column contains some html code, but this is rendered as simple text and not interpreted by the web browser.

Is there any way to archive my need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a slight modification of your query (note **IMG** tags):

```
select '<img src="#APP_IMAGES#counter.png" </img>' img_src
  ,'Counter' title
  , 'This element is conformated by 3 sections: <ul><li>Prueba</li></ul> ' content
  ,' ' btn_label_1
  ,' ' btn_label_2
from dual
```

and a little bit of IMG_SRC and CONTENT columns adjustment - open their properties, scroll down and you'll see the **Escape special characters** - set it to NO.

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks, I found the option in the CONTENT column :D